# Override -j setting for one source file?

Tags: gnu-make

I have a [test script](https://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp/blob/master/cryptest.sh#L188) that takes from hours to days to run. The test script repeatedly builds a library and runs its self tests under different configurations.

On desktops and servers, the script enjoys a speedup because it uses `-j N`, where `N` is the number of cores available. It will take about 2 hours to run the test script.

On dev-boards like a [LeMaker Hikey (8-core ARM64/2GB RAM)](https://www.96boards.org/products/ce/hikey/) and [CubieTruck (8-core ARM/2GB RAM)](http://www.cnx-software.com/2015/08/03/cubieboard-5-aka-cubietruck-plus-development-board-is-powered-by-allwinner-h8-soc/), I can't use `-j N` (for even `N=2` or `N=4`) because one file is a real monster and causes an OOM kill. In this case it can take days for the script to run.

My question is, how can I craft a `make` recipe that tells GNUmake to handle this one source file with `-j 1`? Is it even possible?

Comment: If you have multiple modules, consider building the big library with only one core.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it is possible. It isn't clear how Make splits jobs amongst cores.

[4.9 Special Built-in Target Names](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Special-Targets.html#Special-Targets) mentions

> .NOTPARALLEL
>
> - If `.NOTPARALLEL` is mentioned as a target, then this invocation of make will be run serially, even if the `-j` option is given. Any
>     recursively invoked make command will still run recipes in parallel
>     (unless its makefile also contains this target). Any prerequisites on
>     this target are ignored.

However, [5.7.3 Communicating Options to a Sub-`make`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Options_002fRecursion.html#Options_002fRecursion) says:

> The `-j` option is a special case (see [Parallel
>   Execution](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Parallel.html#Parallel)).
>   If you set it to some numeric value `N` and your operating system
>   supports it (most any UNIX system will; others typically won’t), the
>   parent make and all the sub-makes will communicate to ensure that
>   there are only `N` jobs running at the same time between them all.
>   Note that any job that is marked recursive (see Instead of Executing
>   Recipes) doesn’t count against the total jobs (otherwise we could get
>   `N` sub-makes running and have no slots left over for any real work!)
>
> If your operating system doesn’t support the above communication, then
>   `-j 1` is always put into MAKEFLAGS instead of the value you
>   specified. This is because if the `-j` option were passed down to
>   sub-makes, you would get many more jobs running in parallel than you
>   asked for. If you give `-j` with no numeric argument, meaning to run
>   as many jobs as possible in parallel, this is passed down, since
>   multiple infinities are no more than one.

This suggests to me there is no way to assign a specific job to a single core. It's worth giving a shot though.

Comment: Thanks. I tried adding a `.NOTPARALLEL: regtest.cpp`, but it resulted in serializing the build. IBM has [clearmake](ftp://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/rational/docs/docset/doc/cpf_4.2/ccase_ux/ccbuild/ccbuild-81.html) with better documentation. But under GNU's make, `.NOTPARALLEL: regtest.cpp libcryptopp.a libcryptopp.dylib libcryptopp.so` still serialized the build.

Comment: @jww Try the [`--max-load`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Options-Summary.html#Options-Summary) switch. `Specifies that no new recipes should be started if there are other recipes running and the load average is at least load (a floating-point number). With no argument, removes a previous load limit.` Again, it's pretty vague but it seems like you should be able to set the load limit for that one recipe.

Answer (score 0):

Make the large target first,
then everything else afterwards in parallel.

```
.PHONY: all
all:
    ⋮

.PHONY: all-limited-memory
all-limited-memory:
    ${MAKE} -j1 bigfile
    ${MAKE} all
```

So now

- `$ make -j16 all` works as expected.
- `$ make -j4 all-memory-limited` builds *bigfile* serially (exiting if error), carrying on to do the rest in parallel.